# How to handle filter box that appears while using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I go to a `web page` in `chrome` using `selenium python`. After going to a page ,I click on an item called "search". As I click on it a `filterbox` appears as below

[image]

What should I do to click on restrict by `date` and fill values inside `from` and `to` box and submit using `selenium python`? Sorry I am new to `selenium`, I cant find any examples that satisfy my requirements.This filter box doesnt have a URL associated with it.

Here is the back end source code I found:

```
<div class="hd" id="alert_search_dialog_h" style="cursor: move;">
                    Search Criteria
                </div>

<form action="/portal/alerts" id="alert_search_form" method="get" onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('/portal/alerts', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;">            <input id="search_startTimeXml" name="search[startTimeXml]" type="hidden">
            <input id="search_endTimeXml" name="search[endTimeXml]" type="hidden">
            <input id="search_limit" name="search[limit]" type="hidden" value="50">
            <input id="search_offset" name="search[offset]" type="hidden" value="0">

    <fieldset><legend><input class="restrict_checkboxes" id="include_id" name="include_id" onclick="javascript: admin.alerts.SearchDialog.disableByCheckbox(this, &quot;id_field&quot;);" type="checkbox" value="1">Restrict by ID</legend>
        <div id="id_field" class="disabled">
            <label for="alert_id">Alarm ID</label>
            <input id="search_alert_id" name="search[alert_id]" type="text" disabled="">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend><input class="restrict_dropdown" id="include_route" name="include_route" onclick="javascript: admin.alerts.SearchDialog.disableByCheckbox(this, &quot;type_drop_down_list&quot;);" type="checkbox" value="1">Restrict by route</legend>

         <input id="search_route_min_distance" name="search[route_min_distance]" type="hidden">
         <input id="search_route_max_distance" name="search[route_max_distance]" type="hidden">
         <input id="search_route_min_velocity" name="search[route_min_velocity]" type="hidden">
         <input id="search_route_max_velocity" name="search[route_max_velocity]" type="hidden">
        <div id="type_drop_down_list" class="dropdown_list disabled">
            <table>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>Route ID</th>
                    <td>

                        <select id="search_route_id" name="search[route_id]" onchange="change_route_directions(this.value)"><option value="">--All--</option>
</select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Route direction</th>
                    <td>


                        <select id="search_route_direction" name="search[route_direction]"><option value="">--All--</option>
</select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Distance(<span>m</span>)</th>
                    <td>
                        min
                        <input id="search_route_min_distance_" name="search[route_min_distance_]" size="8" type="text" disabled="">
                        max
                        <input id="search_route_max_distance_" name="search[route_max_distance_]" size="8" type="text" disabled="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Velocity (m/s):
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        min
                        <input id="search_route_min_velocity_" name="search[route_min_velocity_]" size="8" type="text" disabled="">
                        max
                        <input id="search_route_max_velocity_" name="search[route_max_velocity_]" size="8" type="text" disabled="">
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody></table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend><input class="restrict_checkboxes" id="include_type" name="include_type" onclick="javascript: admin.alerts.SearchDialog.disableByCheckbox(this, &quot;type_check_box_list&quot;);" type="checkbox" value="1">Restrict by alarm type</legend>
        <div id="type_check_box_list" class="checkbox_list disabled" style="max-height:100px;-webkit-columns: 100px 2;">

                <input id="search_name_" name="search[name][]" type="checkbox" value="digging_alert" disabled="">
                Digging<br>

                <input id="search_name_" name="search[name][]" type="checkbox" value="fibre_break_alert" disabled="">
                Fibre Break<br>

                <input id="search_name_" name="search[name][]" type="checkbox" value="helios" disabled="">
                Helios Unit Failure<br>

                <input id="search_name_" name="search[name][]" type="checkbox" value="mech_digging_alert" disabled="">
                Mechanized Digging<br>

                <input id="search_name_" name="search[name][]" type="checkbox" value="panoptes" disabled="">
                Panoptes Failure<br>

                <input id="search_name_" name="search[name][]" type="checkbox" value="unknown_alert" disabled="">
                Unknown<br>

                <input id="search_name_" name="search[name][]" type="checkbox" value="vehicle_alert" disabled="">
                Vehicle<br>

                <input id="search_name_" name="search[name][]" type="checkbox" value="walk_alert" disabled="">
                Walking<br>

        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend><input class="restrict_checkboxes" id="include_threat" name="include_threat" onclick="javascript: admin.alerts.SearchDialog.disableByCheckbox(this, &quot;threat_check_box_list&quot;);" type="checkbox" value="1">Restrict by threat level</legend>
    <div id="threat_check_box_list" class="checkbox_list disabled" style="-webkit-columns: 100px 2;">

                <input id="search_threat_level_" name="search[threat_level][]" type="checkbox" value="red" disabled="">
                Red<br>

                <input id="search_threat_level_" name="search[threat_level][]" type="checkbox" value="amber" disabled="">
                Amber<br>

                <input id="search_threat_level_" name="search[threat_level][]" type="checkbox" value="green" disabled="">
                Green<br>

                <input id="search_threat_level_" name="search[threat_level][]" type="checkbox" value="clear" disabled="">
                Clear<br>

    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend><input class="restrict_checkboxes" id="include_status" name="include_status" onclick="javascript: admin.alerts.SearchDialog.disableByCheckbox(this, &quot;status_check_box_list&quot;);" type="checkbox" value="1">Restrict by alarm status</legend>
        <div id="status_check_box_list" class="checkbox_list disabled" style="-webkit-columns: 100px 3;">

                <input id="search_status_" name="search[status][]" type="checkbox" value="acknowledged" disabled="">
                Acknowledged<br>

                <input id="search_status_" name="search[status][]" type="checkbox" value="new" disabled="">
                New<br>

                <input id="search_status_" name="search[status][]" type="checkbox" value="resolved" disabled="">
                Resolved<br>

        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend><input class="restrict_checkboxes" id="include_date" name="include_date" onclick="javascript: admin.alerts.SearchDialog.disableByCheckbox(this, &quot;date_table&quot;);" type="checkbox" value="1">Restrict by date</legend>

        <table id="date_table" class="disabled">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><label for="start_time">From</label></td>
                <td>            <input type="text" name="start_time" id="start_timeId" size="12" value="" disabled="">
                <img alt="Img" id="start_timeImg" onmouseout="this.style.background='';" onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" src="/javascripts/fotech/common_gui/jscalendar/img.gif?1570706592" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Select min date/time">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                _fotechSetupCalendar('start_time',{}); 
            </script>
</td>
                <td><label for="end_time">To</label></td>
                <td>            <input type="text" name="end_time" id="end_timeId" size="12" value="" disabled="">
                <img alt="Img" id="end_timeImg" onmouseout="this.style.background='';" onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" src="/javascripts/fotech/common_gui/jscalendar/img.gif?1570706592" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Select max date/time">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                _fotechSetupCalendar('end_time',{}); 
            </script>
</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </fieldset>

    <table>
        <tbody><tr>
            <th><label for="search_order_by">Order by</label></th>
            <td>
                <select id="search_order_by" name="search[order_by]"><option value="time">Time</option>
<option value="name">Alarm type</option>
<option value="status">Status</option></select>
                <select id="search_order_dir" name="search[order_dir]"><option value="asc">Ascending</option>
<option value="desc">Descending</option></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input id="search_include_suppressed" name="search[include_suppressed]" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <label for="search_include_suppressed">Include suppressed</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</form>
```

Comment: What did you try? please post corresponding html source

Comment: Can you just tell me the overall procedure?

Comment: Kindly add some more code and the HTML source by inspecting the filter area.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to work first with Chrome to understand the site structure and understand what you want to click and how, and only then to write the code that will run with selenium.

Chrome DevTools is a set of web developer tools built directly into the Google Chrome

When you want to work with the DOM or CSS, right-click an element on the page and select Inspect to jump into the Elements panel. Or press Command+Option+C (Mac) or Control+Shift+C (Windows, Linux, Chrome OS).

[Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools)